# How can i parse the Multiple images in the description tag of my RSS feed to my description page using Javascript and regex

Tags: javascript, regex, image, parsing, rss

This is the sample for description tag

```
    <description>
    On 5th September, 2013 ICSK Junior Branch students expressed their love and respect                                for their teachers.<div align=center><img src=http://www.example.com/press//press/sep2613focus1.jpg></div> <div       align=center><img src=http://www.example.com/press//press/sep2613focus3.jpg></div>
     The  highlight of the day was address by Principal Incharge, educating children on the significance of the Day. Indeed a touching day for the teaching fraternity of ICSK. <div align=center><img src=http://www.example.com/press//press/sep2613focus4.jpg></div> More ICSK News at <a href="http://www.icsk-kw.com" target = "_blank">www.icsk-kw.com</a>
    </description>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really **have** to use RegEx (which is **not** what you should do in the first place), then you can use this (rather simple) expression:

```
// description contains the text that you provided
images = description.match(/<img src=[^>]+>/g);
```

*images* now contains an array with all image tags.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Am able to get one image now.How can i use your code to display multiple images in the description tag using Imageview below.I tried with while loop but not working.Please help.Thanks in advance                                             var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                  image:e.row.image,
                  top:20,
                  height:160,
                  width:200
 
                });
                sv.add(image);